# Center an element between the highest and the lowest characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

How can I vertically center an element between the highest and the lowest characters of another element (ideally only CSS but ok for JS)?

I mean relatively to the characters that are present (the actual text content), not to the line height (which is not responsive to the characters).

The goal is to align an element with the "perceived middle" of a text.

[image: diagram]

Comment: have you tried vertical align? have you tried anything?

Comment: What do you want to happen if for example there wasn't the T there, of if there wasn't the g? i.e. are you looking for the vertical center of the font as a whole or only of the characters that are present.

Comment: I've been trying for an hour. Vertical align is relative to the middle of the line height, which is not what I want.

Comment: If there wasn't the T there, the relative middle would be between the top of the o/g and the bottom of the g. I don't want the middle of the line height, I want it to be relative to the characters that are present.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925003/8620333

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, you can see the difference in the snippet.

[image: Heights in fonts]

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

section {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: .8em;
}

h1,
h2 {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Height set to 1em</p>
  <div>
    <h1>oTg</h1>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconIndent" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M0 5v8l4.5-4z"></path></svg>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
      <p>Default height</p>
      <div>
        <h2>oTg</h2>
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconIndent" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M0 5v8l4.5-4z"></path></svg>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the height to be relative to the characters, not hardcoded.

Comment: The height is 1em which is going to be relative to the characters. Look at the example again where it shows the difference between height being 1em and the default line-height.

Comment: If you want the height to change according to the content of the text, then this is going to be very difficult. ;)

Comment: Yes I want the height to be relative to the content of the text.